# How can I set an absolute image url for Open Graph Image tags?

Tags: templating, image-transforms

I need the final tag to look like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/uploads/resources/_hero/myimage.jpg">
```

If I use something like this:

```
{% set seoImage = entry.featuredImage.one().getUrl('hero') %}
```

I end up with a relative URL:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/uploads/resources/_hero/myimage.jpg"
```

So I thought "okay, I'll concatenate the site URL to the front and trim off one of the backslashes":

```
{% set seoImage = siteUrl ~ entry.featuredImage.one().getUrl('hero')|trim('/', 'left') %}
```

That worked fine until the server has to generate a new image using image transform. Then we end up, just the once, with a URL that looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/http://mysite.com/index.php/actions/assets/generate-transform?transformId=46">"
```

Darn, No idea what to do from here. Any ideas on how to get an absolute URL for the OG image tag EVERY time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the reason this is happening is because you did not set an absolute Base URL in your asset settings. So if you use `/assets/images/folder` in your asset settings, that's what the urls will look like on the frontend. If you instead use `http://my-project.com/assets/images/folder`, your asset urls will include the domain name.

---

I'd recommend setting up [Yii Aliases in your config](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/#aliases) (if you haven't already) and using those instead of hard-coding the url. So you'd do something like this in Craft's `general.php` config:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@assetBaseUrl' => 'http://my-project.com/assets',
    '@assetBasePath' => '/path/to/web/assets',
],
```

And then in your asset settings you'd be able to use `@assetBaseUrl/images/folder` instead of `http://my-project.com/assets/images/folder`. Just a way to keep everything as DRY and clean as possible

---

The above solution should solve your issue, but fwiw, I'm pretty sure you can force your site to use absolute urls regardless of your asset settings. If you use the `url()` method and specify what scheme you want, I believe it will always resolve to an absolute url. So something like the following should work (but it feels very icky to me):

```
{% set seoImage = entry.featuredImage.one().getUrl('hero') %}
{% set absoluteImageUrl = url(seoImage, '', 'https') %}
```

Comment: Awesome! I like the aliases approach. I do have it set, but it's a relative path. No wonders. :)